# How to use on_message using discord.py in this way?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot using discord.py. I want the bot to get triggered if a message from any user(on the server where the bot is present) is a `mixture` of `Integers`, `Characters` and `Strings` like this e.g `122-PG-CSAI-2022`

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think the difference is between a `char` and `string` in this case, but this code will check if it contains at least one alphabetical letter and one `int`:

```
on_message(message):
    has_number = any(char.isdigit() for char in message.content)
    has_non_number = any(char.islapha() for char in message.content)

    if has_number and has_non_number:
        # do something
```

edit:

```
on_message(message):
    splits = message.content.split("-")

    # it's not in the wanted format
    if len(splits) != 4:
        # return or something else

    cont = True

    # check if first is a number within range <1, 999>
    try:
        if int(splits[0]) <= 0 and int(splits[0] >= 1000:
            cont = False
    except ValueError:
        cont = False

    # check if second is one of the options
    if splits[1] not in ["UG", "PG", "D"]:
        cont = False

    # check if third is one of the options
    if splits[2] not in ["some", "options", "here"]:
        cont = False

    # check if fourth is a number from range <2022 ...>
    try:
        if int(splits[3]) < 2022:
            cont = False
    except ValueError:
        cont = False

    # it fits all the criteria
    if cont:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Actually I want to code to get triggered if the message from the user is like this `123-UG-CSE-2021` and then add a role to the user. The first integer part will have 3-digits from 001 to 999, the first String part will have 3 options either UG/PG/D and the 2nd String part have some options and the last part will be any year from and after 2022

Comment: that's a lot different task. you could split the message by `"-"` and then approach each element on its own. Cast first one to `int`, check if it's within the range. Check the second and third if they have proper lenghts, and if they are alphabetical. Cast last to `int`, check range again.

Comment: Have you heard about regular expressions? @SoumyajoyDas

Comment: No actually I'm new in bot development and I've heard about regular expressions

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh can you share the code I'm a bit confused

Comment: updated the answer for your specific task

Comment: I'm adding an Answer to my question can you please check it? What wrong have I done again? The bot is ignoring the messages which are not of the type I wanted but I'm getting some error when I'm running the code. Your help would really be appreciated :)

Comment: you moved the `cont` variable inside the `if` condition. You should use `return` or something similar inside the first `if`, otherwise the rest of the code can throw some errors later on

Comment: Can you please explain where I've to return? Or can you copy my code and correct my error by editing the answer you've given. I shall really be grateful to you

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you once again. The code is working fine and the bot can now assign roles if the user writes the specific code but I'm having one issue :( along with that code I've set a custom help command with a custom prefix I have set None for the default help command. But the bot is ignoring the commands when verification process is working :/ Can you please lemme know how to fix that code?

Comment: you should try to look for a solution first, if you can't find anything, ask a new question with the new problem described

Answer (score 0):

By Integers, Characters, and Strings, I assume you mean no special characters (i.e. @, !, *, &, etc.) If so, this works:

```
on_message(message):
    for char in message.content:
       if not char.isdigit() and not char.isalpha(): return False
    #trigger bot here
```

Comment: By char I mean only one special character i.e., hypen - which will differential Integers and Strings

Comment: Example of Message on which I want the bot to get triggered is `123-UG-CSE-2021`

Comment: Actually I want to code to get triggered if the message from the user is like this `123-UG-CSE-2021` and then add a role to the user. The first integer part will have 3-digits from 001 to 999, the first String part will have 3 options either UG/PG/D and the 2nd String part have some options and the last part will be any year from and after 2022

Comment: You would probably go about that by splitting the string into each section using the `"-"`, then check each section individually against those parameters